# how to query date stored as int(11)

Tags: php, mysql, date

The date is stored in int(11) as default for fuelphp. Now I want to extract data as per month and year for archive.i.e. use mysql query using condition as MONTH(date) = 'February' AND YEAR(date) = '2014'.
I tried using following mysql query but to no avail.

```
SELECT
    contents.*,
    menus.menu_parent,
    categories.category_alias
FROM
    contents
LEFT JOIN
    menus ON menus.link = contents.id
JOIN
    categories ON categories.id = contents.category_id
WHERE
    contents.status = '1' AND
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(contents.`published_date`), '%Y %M') = '2014 January' AND
    contents.category_id = 3
```

The date value in database looks something like this:
for August 17th, 2014 - 1408212900
for March 27th, 2015 - 1427393700

During storing into database: strtotime(date)

How am I to solve this?
Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and show examples of what the values look like.

Comment: What does the date value look like?

Comment: You mean UNIX timestamp by int ?

Comment: `but to no avail` you should elaborate on that. Is there any error messages, is the result not what you're expecting, what the results are, and what they should be, etc.

Comment: @LieRyan The current year is data is coming true but for previous dates data is null also when there is data stored.

Comment: Why not just get the `strtotime()` before building your query?

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this will help you:

```
SELECT contents.*, menus.menu_parent, categories.category_alias 
FROM contents 
LEFT JOIN menus ON menus.link = contents.id 
JOIN categories ON categories.id = contents.category_id 
WHERE contents.status = '1' 
AND MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_activity)) = 'January'
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_activity)) = 2014
AND contents.category_id = 3;
```

you can convert first the field you are going to compare to an actual date using

```
FROM_UNIXTIME
```

for more information regarding date time functions in MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Edit:
for query improvement, you can combine the two:

```
SELECT contents.*, menus.menu_parent, categories.category_alias 
FROM contents 
LEFT JOIN menus ON menus.link = contents.id 
JOIN categories ON categories.id = contents.category_id 
WHERE contents.status = '1' 
AND DATE_FORMAT((FROM_UNIXTIME(last_activity)),'%M-%Y') = 'January-2014'
AND contents.category_id = 3;
```

Comment: @Arzgethalm The query runs good but why doesn't it works for january 1st? It works perfectly well for january 2nd but not for january 1st. Why?

Comment: @sammy if you are going to filter days too. just add it in the condition: DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_activity)) = 1 for specific days

Comment: @Arzgethalm No, I don't need for specific days but the problem is if the date is january 1st 2014 and I query for january and 2014 it doesm't give the data. That's the problem.

Comment: @sammy are there any entries for january 1st? DATE_FORMAT((FROM_UNIXTIME(last_activity)),'%d-%M-%Y') = '01-January-2015' try to check if they do exist.